# On covers of groups by cosets

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that ${\cal A}=\{a_sG_s\}_{s=1}^k$ is a cover of a group $G$ by (finitely many) left cosets with $a_tG_t$ irredundant (where $1\le t\le k$). Then the index $[G:G_t]$ is known to be finite. In my paper with G. Lettl [[*On covers of abelian groups by cosets*](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/103g.pdf), Acta Arith. 131(2008), no. 4, 341-350] we proved that if $G$
is abelian then $k\ge1+f([G:G_t])$, where the Mycielski function $f$ 
is defined by 
 $$f\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{\alpha_i}\bigg)=\sum_{i=1}^r\alpha_i(p_i-1)$$
with $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ distinct primes and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. By my intuition, this might be extended to any group.

QUESTION: Let ${\cal A}=\{a_sG_s\}_{s=1}^k$ be a cover of a group $G$ by (finitely many) left cosets with $a_tG_t$ irredundant. Does the inequality  $k\ge1+f([G:G_t])$ always hold?

I feel that the question should have a positive answer. Your comments are welcome!

Comment: "*Then the index $[G:G_t]$ is known to be finite*"; you mean, finite for each $t$?

Comment: @YCor Neumann's original result states that if $\{a_sG_s\}_{s=1}^k$ is a cover of $G$ but none of its proper subsystems is,  then $[G:G_t]<\infty$ for all $t=1,\ldots,k$.

Comment: In my posting I fix $1\le t\le k$. If the left coest $a_tG_t$ in the cover is irredundant then $[G:G_t]$ must be finite.

Comment: Yes, your previous comment was already clear.

Comment: I'd avoid "Is it true that... is there a counterexample" because it makes a "Yes" answer ambiguous. Since you expect a positive answer, you can leave it in the positive... everybody here knows that a negative answer means providing a counterexample :)

Comment: @YCor Thanks. I have reedited the posting in view of your comments.

Comment: But you erased "for each $t$" and this makes again the first statement unclear without reading the comments. Especially insofar as one formulation of Neumann's result says "there exists $t$ such that".

Comment: No problem. I let $t$ fixed. If $a_tG_t$ is irredundant then there is a minimal subcover $\{a_sG_s\}_{s\in I}$ of $\{a_sG_s\}_{s=1}^k$ with $t\in I$.

Comment: I guess you can edit and put again "for each/every $t$", and then we could erase this whole discussion.

Comment: I hope you have understood my last reply. No problem with $t$ fixed.